# How to disable the reset upon submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

How can I maintain the value of the form when I submit it?

```
<select name="Year">
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
```

Comment: which backend language are u using?

Comment: It's not a reset it's a refresh

Comment: Can you provide a little more information as to what you are trying to do? Keeping the value after a hard submit?

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: Ghost is not responding...

Comment: i'm sorry for the delay I was excited working, im using JSP. I'm working on an filter, if I click the "Filter" the select tag return to the default. I'm using chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jquery (you tagged it): Submit your form via $.post to your php script. Something like

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $.post("URL/TO/FORM.PHP", $(this).serializeArray(), function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

So you submit your form to your script but the site don't refresh because you set the return to false. You can get the url to your script from your action="" like this

```
$("form").attr("action")
```

Comment: I've never worked with JSP but it seems to work. Have a look on this site: http://www.programming-free.com/2012/08/ajax-with-jsp-and-servlet-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php then:

```
<select name="Year">
    <option value="2013" <?php if($_REQUEST['Year']=='2013'){echo "selected"}?>>2013</option>
    <option value="2014" <?php if($_REQUEST['Year']=='2014'){echo "selected"}?>>2014</option>
    <option value="2015" <?php if($_REQUEST['Year']=='2015'){echo "selected"}?>>2015</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
```

Comment: how you know he is using `php` ?

Comment: @Tushar Gupta : I said "if you are using php then"

Comment: I don't think just echoing "selected" will work in all browsers.  Should be "selected=true".